# Как расположить 2 DataFrame на одном листе excel рядом друг с другом?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

Подскажите, как можно расположить второй DataFrame рядом с первым?

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)

result = df2.loc[df2.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1', header=None, index=False)
wb1 = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
sheet1 = wb1.active
sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 130
wb1.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
print(df2)

result2 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
with ExcelWriter(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
result2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Лист1", startrow=0, startcol=6, header=None, index=False)
wb1 = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
sheet1 = wb1['Лист1']
sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 130
wb1.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
print(df3)
```

Если просто использовать

```
> startrow=0, startcol=6
```

...то программа падает с ошибкой при попытке записать DF2.

Comment: Проще всего объединить фреймы в один и записать в Excel объединенный фрейм

Comment: @MaxU возможно же второй фрейм поместить под первым без усилий  задав один и тот же лист не ужели так же просто нельзя задать координаты и поместить второй фрейм, но рядом с первым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать но только в новом листе Excel файла:

```
In [28]: with pd.ExcelWriter("1.xlsx") as writer:
    ...:     d1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    ...:     d2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startcol=5)
```

данные:

```
In [29]: d1
Out[29]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [30]: d2
Out[30]:
    d   e
0  10  11
1  12  13
2  14  15
3  16  17
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS для того чтобы добавить DataFrame к уже существующему листу в Excel файле, **не перезаписывая его**, можно воспользоваться [этим решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205).