# Как задать промежуток между колонками?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

С помощью данной конструкции

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)

result = df2.loc[df2.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
result2 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]

datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result2]], axis=1)

datafr.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2, startcol=0, header=None, index=False)
```

объединяю фреймы и получаю колонки которые идут по порядку друг за другом (колонка A,B,C,D,E,F)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как получить такой результат что бы пропуск был через колонку D (A,B,C;D;E,F,G)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понятно же.

Comment: @strawdog дополнил вопрос.

Comment: В excel параметр промежуток между колонками - отсутствует, это в html такой  параметр есть. Красота в excel делается параметрами: ширина колонки, выравнивание лево/право/центр/верх/низ.

Comment: Я вроде бы уже вам показывал как это сделать в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1368729/211923

Comment: @MaxU к сложению тот код для которого я спрашивал мне не совсем подошёл в плане удобства поэтому я объединил фреймы datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result2]], axis=1)  и ищу способ как их разделить да именно как в той теме что вы привели.

Comment: Попробуйте вставить пустой столбец df.insert(3, " ", "") ?

Comment: @MaxU это то что нужно поставьте пожалуйста в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.insert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(3, " ", "")
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста если мне нужно будет добавить  2 промежутка между колонками то как эта дополнить эту конструкцию? Как пример df.insert(3, " ", 6, "" , "") но эта конструкция не верна.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, вызовите `df.insert` два раза. При втором вызове учитывайте добавленную строку для указания индекса

Comment: Так пробовал  datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result3]], axis=0)
                 datafr.insert(5, " ", "")
                 datafr1 = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [datafr, result2, result4]], axis=1)
                 datafr1.insert(11, " ", "")  выдаёт ошибку     raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert  , already exists

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, воспользуйтесь параметром `allow_duplicates=True`